# Libcurl:can't send custom headers to requestbin?

Tags: c, curl, web-scraping, http-headers, libcurl

This is the code

```
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(){
   CURL * curl;
   curl=curl_easy_init();
   struct curl_slist *headers=NULL;
   headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Connection: keep-alive");
   headers = curl_slist_append(headers,"a : b");
   curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_URL,"requestb.in/1ar78su1");
   curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,headers);
   curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
   curl_easy_perform(curl);
   curl_slist_free_all(headers);
  }
```

Heres the requestbin link:  ,
why doesn't it show "a : b" and "Connection : keep-alive" on requestbin?

Comment: Did you try with complete address including `https://`?

Comment: @Xaqron Just tried it, same results.

Comment: add custom header in right syntax and try again.`"a: b"` instead of `"a : b"` (note the space between `a` and `:`)

Comment: @Xaqron Thanks, it worked for "a: b", but how do I replace existing "Connection: close" with "Connection: keep-alive" ?

Comment: `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE, 1L);`

Comment: @Xaqron I tried that earlier, doesn't change anything, I think it doesn't matter and as you said, depends on requestbin itself.

Comment: Note that unlike custom headers when you set default headers like `connection type` underlying library will overwrite your value so in this case you should use built-in functionality. See: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE.html

Comment: @Xaqron: no, that option is for TCP keep-alive, which is something completely different. RealGas: curl doesn't normally send "Connection: close" at all so your problem is a mystery to me. Can you show the full request you send?